# How to replace a value of an XML block of code inside a JSON file using a Python script

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I want to create a Python script which parses a JSON file.
Inside the JSON file there is an XML structure.
I want to replace a specific field of that XML structure with a new value.
To be more specific, i try to replace the "registeredBy" field with a new value i want.
I need to do this for multiple files, so i need the script.

I' m new to Python. So far i can open the JSON file and create a new value (commented out Python code). I still try to figure out how to enter the XML code block and replace the field i want with a new value.

Any suggestions on what/where to read are welcome.

Thank you.

```
{
    "creationDate": 1542716832357,
    "id": "15f66daf-1fc3-46b5-9d0e-915bc8058c52",
    "payload": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tns:service xmlns:tns=\"http://example.com\"><tns:category>data</tns:category><tns:description>Service Description.</tns:description><tns:serviceMetadata><tns:registeredAt>1542386903532</tns:registeredAt><tns:registeredBy>George Papadopoulos</tns:registeredBy></tns:serviceMetadata></tns:service>",
    "resource": {
        "creationDate": 1542386903542,
        "id": "0b5dd030-af5e-4b1a-8be3-1b5e195615e2",
        "modificationDate": 1549460188076,
        "payload": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tns:service xmlns:tns=\"http://example.com\"><tns:category>data</tns:category><tns:description>Service Description.</tns:description><tns:serviceMetadata><tns:registeredAt>1542386903532</tns:registeredAt><tns:registeredBy>George Papadopoulos</tns:registeredBy></tns:serviceMetadata></tns:service>",
        "payloadFormat": "xml",
        "resourceTypeName": "service",
        "version": "02062019133628"
    }
}
```

```
import json

with open('this.json', 'r') as json_file:
     json_data = json.load(json_file)
     for item in json_data:
           if item['registeredBy'] in ["George Papadopoulos"]:
              item['registeredBy'] = "Nick"
with open('this.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json_data, json_file, indent=2)


#with open('this.json', 'r') as json_file:
#    json_data = json.load(json_file)
#    json_data['registeredBy'] = "Nick"
#
#with open('this.json', 'w') as json_file:
#    json_file.write(json.dumps(json_data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to break it down to 3 steps:

1. Parse Json
2. Parse XML
3. save changes

First, get the XML part from json

```
import json

with open('this.json', 'r') as json_file:
     json_data = json.load(json_file)

# this is the first payload, the payload under resource seems identical 
# so we will copy the updated xml over after the change
xml = json_data['payload']
```

Second, change xml data. You may need to install `bs4` and `lxml` packages

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_data = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'xml')
for tag in xml_data.find_all('tns:registeredBy'):
    tag.string='0' # change '0' to whatever you want
```

Lastly, save changes back

```
json_data['payload'] = str(xml_data)
json_data['resource']['payload'] = json_data['payload']  # we can just copy the same xml over, since they were the same before change

# write to file
with open('this.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(json_data, json_file, indent=2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a minor fix, in the second open i need to open as json_file again, else it produces an I/O error.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a string manipulation.

Convert the json to string, then `.replace()`, then write back to file:

```
json_data = {
    "creationDate": 1542716832357,
    "id": "15f66daf-1fc3-46b5-9d0e-915bc8058c52",
    "payload": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tns:service xmlns:tns=\"http://example.com\"><tns:category>data</tns:category><tns:description>Service Description.</tns:description><tns:serviceMetadata><tns:registeredAt>1542386903532</tns:registeredAt><tns:registeredBy>George Papadopoulos</tns:registeredBy></tns:serviceMetadata></tns:service>",
    "resource": {
        "creationDate": 1542386903542,
        "id": "0b5dd030-af5e-4b1a-8be3-1b5e195615e2",
        "modificationDate": 1549460188076,
        "payload": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><tns:service xmlns:tns=\"http://example.com\"><tns:category>data</tns:category><tns:description>Service Description.</tns:description><tns:serviceMetadata><tns:registeredAt>1542386903532</tns:registeredAt><tns:registeredBy>George Papadopoulos</tns:registeredBy></tns:serviceMetadata></tns:service>",
        "payloadFormat": "xml",
        "resourceTypeName": "service",
        "version": "02062019133628"
    }
}



import json

jsonStr = json.dumps(json_data).replace('<tns:registeredBy>George Papadopoulos</tns','<tns:registeredBy>Nick</tns')
with open('C:/this.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(json.loads(jsonStr), file, indent=2)
```

Comment: if the solution worked out, be sure to accept the answer

Comment: ah yes. Didnt see that one above. Yes, that's a better solution.